# Where can I find a flight log archive for commercial flights?

Tags: faa

I heard that commercial flight logs are publicly available from the FAA, including mechanical delay reasons, etc.  Is this true?  If so, where can this information be found?

Answer (score 3):

Under the Freedom of Information Act you can request these records from the FAA. Please read more about doing so here:
http://www.faa.gov/foia/foia_request/

Answer (score 1):

The data you want is here: http://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time

Select pre-zipped file to get all fields. You have to download it one month at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Flight Aware](http://flightaware.com/) allows you to view filed flight plans. It also lets you know where the aircraft is in-flight, although I am not sure how accurate that information is.

Comment: Yes, I did find my flight on that site, but no other information was available other than the takeoff/landing time.

Comment: Hmm, not sure where you can find more information then. Sorry :-\